# A non-linear coupled second order ODE for a geodesic

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, nonlinear-system, geodesic

Let $g = (dx)^2 + e^x (dy)^2$ be a Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$. I want to find the equation of the geodesic. To do this, I know that I can solve a system of coupled non-linear second order ODEs. After calculating the Christoffel symbols, I have arrived at the following system for $\gamma(t)=(\gamma^1(t),\gamma^2(t)) =(u(t),v(t))$:
$$ u''-\frac{1}{2}e^u(v')^2 =0 $$
$$ v''+u'v'=0 $$
I'm not very familiar with ODEs beyond the basic techniques that one might learn in a first course. I started by guessing $u=-k\log t$ for some $k>0$, but this turned out to not work. Can someone help me solve this system?  This is not for homework. I wanted to do an example to help me better understand parallel transport, but it ended up being too complicated. Thanks.

EDIT: Intuitively, I feel like a geodesic from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$ will travel in a path that sticks closely to the $y$-axis for most of its time, because $e^x$ makes $g$ "lengthier" the bigger the value of $x$. This led me to guess a solution that is like $\log t$, but I don't know if this intuition is correct.

[image]

Per AlexanderJ93's solution, I have graphed the parameterization on Desmos for $a=b=c=1$ and got a curve that is roughly what I expected in the previous edit.

[image]

Comment: You might look at my differential geometry text (linked free in my profile) for some examples of these sorts of computations. Look in Section 4 of Chapter 2 and in Section 2 of Chapter 3.

Comment: I don't follow it all, but your last comment made me think that $x^{1/n}$ for large $n$ would stick close to the $y$ axis and might help.

Comment: I also suggest looking at the Jacobi fields, which satisfy a linearization of the geodesic equation. They can show the geometric behavior of geodesics more easily than using the geodesic equation itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm going to focus on the ODE system (for more on the geometry, see Ted Shifrin's comment).

We want to solve the nonlinear system

$$ \begin{align}u'' - \frac{1}{2}v'^2\exp u & = 0 \\ v'' + u'v' & = 0\end{align}$$

Notice that the lowest order of $v$ is actually $v'$, so let's have $w = v'$. This gives us a second equation of

$$ w' + u'w = 0 $$

Multiply through by $\exp(u)$ (standard integrating factor method) to get

$$ \exp(u)w' + u'\exp(u) w = [w\exp(u)]' = 0 $$

and so we can integrate and solve

$$ w = a \exp(-u) $$

Put this into the first equation to get

$$ u'' - \frac{a^2}{2}\exp(-u) = 0 $$

Multiply through by $u'$ to get

$$ u'u'' - \frac{a^2}{2}u'\exp(-u) = \frac{1}{2}\left[u'^2 + a^2\exp(-u)\right]' = 0 $$

Integrate this to get the separable ODE

$$ u' = \sqrt{b^2-a^2\exp(-u)} $$

where $b^2 \geq a^2\exp(-u) \geq 0$. Integrate again

$$ \frac{2}{b}\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{b}\sqrt{b^2-a^2\exp(-u)}\right) = c + t $$

which we can solve explicitly as

$$ u = 2\log\left(\frac{a}{2b}\text{cosh}\left(c+bt\right)\right) $$

(replacing $b$ with $2b$ and $c$ with $bc$ for neatness). Then,

$$v = \int a\exp(-u) \text dt = \frac{4b^2}{a}\int \text{sech}(c+bt) \text dt $$

which we can integrate to

$$ v = \frac{4b^2}{ac}\tan^{-1}\sinh(b+ct) = \frac{4b^2}{ac}\text{gd}(b+ct) $$

where $\text{gd}$ is the Gudermannian function. Thus,

$$ \gamma(t) = \left( 2\log\left(\frac{a}{2b}\text{cosh}\left(c+bt\right)\right) , \frac{4b^2}{ac}\text{gd}(b+ct) \right) $$

Comment: on line 7 you said you forgot to multiply the second term by $u'$ but $u$, i don't know if this changes the solution.

Comment: @LordCommander Ah yes, that's a typo, but the calculation is correct. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I'm still in awe by your solution, it's so elegant, so obvious in a way. I have been trying to solve this for 4 hours now and i feel asleep. What's your trick?

Comment: @LordCommander Practice. The $w = v'$ sub and the integrating factor are pretty standard fare for intro ODE courses I think. The "multiply by $u'$" is a trick I picked up in my grad ODE class. It's an extension of the idea of integrating factors for higher derivatives. Just always be on the look out for higher order product rules!

Comment: Actually i did all of those :D. The missing piece was the $\cdot e^u$ which i absolutely adore.

Answer (score 3):

Haven't checked the system is correct, but by writing $u(0) = u_{0}$, $u'(0) = u_{0}'$, and similarly for $v$, we can solve if $v_{0}' \neq 0$ by writing the second as $\frac{v''}{v'} = -u'$ and integrating to $v' = (e^{u_{0}}v_{0}') e^{-u}$. Substituting into the first gives $u'' - \frac{1}{2}(e^{u_{0}}v_{0}')^{2} e^{-u} = 0$. Multiplying by $u'$ and integrating gives
$$
(u')^{2} + (e^{u_{0}}v_{0}')^{2} e^{-u} = (u_{0}')^{2} + e^{u_{0}} (v_{0}')^{2},
$$
which has the form $(u')^{2} = c_{2} - c_{1}^{2} e^{-u}$. This can be integrated and solved explicitly for $u$ (for example, by substituting $e^{u/2} = (c_{1} \cosh x)/\sqrt{c_{2}}$) and then for $v$, though the details are probably easier to write out oneself than to follow.

Comment: Apparently I was calculating and typing longer than 10 minutes; will leave this as a complement to Alexander's (+1) answer.